# Trouble creating a console menu

Tags: c#

What I need help with is I'm making a menu with the console, or at least attempting to.

I want it to work like this with arrow keys:

```
->Option 1 (Selected hence the > )
  Option 2 (Deselected)
  Option 3 (Deselected)
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Consoletest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ConsoleKeyInfo keypressed;
        public static string[] menu = new string[3] {"Start", "Options", "Exit"};
        public static int menuID = 0;
        public static string selected = menu[0];

        public static void Selected()
        {
            keypressed = Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void printMenu()
        {
            int lengthmenu = menu.Length;
            foreach (var menuElement in menu)
            {
                menuID++;
                menuID.ToString();

                if(selected == menu)
                Console.WriteLine(menuElement.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void checkSelected()
        {
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            printMenu();
            //Selected();
            //checkSelected();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this even the correct way to approach this? It's half finished at the `if` where I gave up and also at the `.ToString` part.

Comment: What does "selection" do? This doesn't sound like the way a user would expect to use a console app either. It sounds like you are going to be knee deep in cursor manipulation soon :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah i was assuming it would get in depth, It was just a experiment really to try and pull it off in the console, Majority of the things i had undone in frustration but i think i accidentally uncommented that part

Comment: You seem to have a decent start, but there are lots of little mistakes in your code. The easiest way to find us (without us simply telling you) is to step through the program in the debugger. That way you can see exactly what happens at every step and figure out where your logic is failing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: how about simply printing the menu every time (with a few newlines for good measure)? It's not pretty, but could be quite useful as a learning exercise. Plus: it has a nice pre-vt100 ring to it. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you could do that, and does have a a very "calculator menu" feel to it. I wouldn't reccommend it for a production project, but for a learning experience, I can think of worse approaches :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Honestly it's not so much where my logic is failing but more or less i dont quiet understand how i can achieve my goal, It seemed alot easier in my head and still feels relatively easy, Im fairly new to C# and haven't messed with arrays much either.

Comment: Depending on your implementation, it could be easy (re-write the whole screen each time) or hard (cursor manipulation). Its certainly not something C# *expects* you to do in a Console, so expecting it to be *simple* is probably a mistake. Also, whats the difference between your logic failing and knowing how to reach your goal? They seem pretty much the same to me...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Now you point out my mistake, It is clear my logic is failing haha, I was hoping to just use different functions as "Screens" for now for the learning process.

Comment: I have no idea what that last statement meant :) You have two (broad) ways of implementing it from myself and @FrankvanPuffelen though, does that at least get you started? Its hard to point out the mistake in your code since you aren't trying to do either of those things in it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can see how i wasnt entirely clear enough in my initial post, Sorry. What i've been looking for is with my current code how can i get the position of the > cursor thing, So like, What item in the array it points too

Comment: Well, youd keep track of the current index, and increment/decrement it when up/down is pressed. You could then simply index into the array. If you are available tomorrow sometime, we could chat and maybe I can clear up some of these more fundamental issues with you. If you are available, just leave me a comment, and I'll set it up.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Hey man, Im available now if you are?

Comment: @TaylorStevens Let me know when you plan to be on this week 8-5 PST, and I'll chat with you.

Comment: Has this been solved? I've written a console menu which sadly does not feature arrow navigation, but maybe it's still interesting to you: https://github.com/nerai/CMenu